# Least squares for circle detection

Tags: python, algorithm, feature-detection, least-squares

I'm trying to perform a circle detection from a laser scan using least squares optimization over a subset of data points. Since the measurements are only obtained for a part of a circle, the least squares method returns faulty result, reporting a circle much closer to the laser than it actually is.

The outcome of the algorithm is shown in the picture. Scatter points indicate the laser measurements, circles are centered on the points returned by the algorithm. Gray semi-transparent shape indicates the robot taking a scan (lasers on the left and on the right of this shape).

I'm interested only in the local coordinates of the circle, which has known radius RR.

PS. I assume that the scan is separated into clusters (self.clusters[i] is one cluster), which are the lists of [x,y] laser points

```
def circle(x, scan):
    xc, yc = x
    f = sqrt((scan[:,0] - xc)**2 + (scan[:,1] - yc)**2) - RR
    return f


def optimize_detect_circles(self):

    centre = [1,1]

    for i in range(0, self.number_of_clusters):
        range_points = np.array(self.clusters[i])

        sol = optimize.root(circle, centre, args=(range_points), method='lm')
        self.circle_candidates.append(sol.x)
        print sol.x
```

Here’s the picture:

[image]

Comment: Try looking into [this](http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf) paper, I recently had to implement it so I'm sure it works.

Comment: For detecting all the circles you can use [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC), you basically randomly sample the space multiple times and try to fit a circle to the sample space, after you have that, you can add all other points that match the model and then depending on the number of points that fit the model decide whether that is a valid circle (ex. consider only those that have at least 10 point)

Comment: Thank you! I have seen your paper and certainly will refer to it if I cannot solve this way. I was hoping to understand at which point the approach above is actually failing.

Comment: I've created a JS library for circle fitting [here](https://github.com/Meakk/circle-fit). It's not in python but maybe it can help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1,1` is too far from the correct value; you most probably fall into some local optimum.

Try starting from a point much closer to the real center. You find it by first fitting a straight line to your cluster; then separate the points into two halves, according to which half of the line they project onto; fit *two* lines next, each  to one of your new two subclusters; and find an intersection point for the two perpendiculars at their middle points.

This is predicated on your clusters being arcs not bigger than 180 degrees in span, which they seem like they are. If not, just repeat the subdivision, to get four chords instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

You can find circles using a [Circular Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform) - this is especially easy if you know the radius of the circle in advance.

Borrowing liberally from the documentation for this process at [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html), I have put together the following code which runs, but might need a bit of tweaking to locate the circles:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import skimage
from skimage import data, filter, io
from skimage.transform import hough_circle
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import data, color
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter

theImage = np.sum(io.imread("w1s31.png"),2)/4 # Image to greyscale

hough_radii = np.arange(61, 69, 2) # These are the radii to search for
hough_res = hough_circle(theImage, hough_radii)
centers = []
accums = []
radii = []

for radius, h in zip(hough_radii, hough_res):
    # For each radius, extract two circles
    num_peaks = 2
    peaks = peak_local_max(h, num_peaks=num_peaks)
    centers.extend(peaks)
    accums.extend(h[peaks[:, 0], peaks[:, 1]])
    radii.extend([radius] * num_peaks)

# Draw the most prominent 5 circles
image = color.gray2rgb(theImage)
for idx in np.argsort(accums)[::-1][:5]:
    center_x, center_y = centers[idx]
    radius = radii[idx]
    cx, cy = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius)
    theImage[cy, cx] = (1)

plt.imshow(theImage, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note: this isn't correct. skimage's `hough_circle` assumes that the input is edges, not greyscale, where nonzero elements represent edges: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.hough_circle (where in this case the input image is greyscale).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small snippet of the circle detection implemented from [this](http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf) paper.
The algorithm always works and is not iterative with a linear complexity.

```js
 
var add = function(a,b){ return a+b; };
var add_uu = function(a,b){ return a+b[0]*b[0]; };
var add_uv = function(a,b){ return a+b[0]*b[1]; };
var add_vv = function(a,b){ return a+b[1]*b[1]; };
var add_uuu = function(a,b){ return a+b[0]*b[0]*b[0]; };
var add_vvv = function(a,b){ return a+b[1]*b[1]*b[1]; };
var add_uvv = function(a,b){ return a+b[0]*b[1]*b[1]; };
var add_uuv = function(a,b){ return a+b[0]*b[0]*b[1]; };
var getx = function(e){ return e[0]; };
var gety = function(e){ return e[1]; };

$(document).ready(function () {
  var paper = Raphael("canvas");
  var points=[];
    
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    var x = e.offsetX;
    var y = e.offsetY;
    points.push([x,y]);
    paper.circle(x, y, 1);
 });
    
 $("#clear").click(function(){
   paper.clear();
   points = [];
 });
    
 $("#go").click(function(){
     var N = points.length;

     var xb = points.map(getx).reduce(add,0) / N;
     var yb = points.map(gety).reduce(add,0) / N;
     
     var u = points.map(function(e){return [e[0]-xb,e[1]-yb];});
     
     var a1 = u.reduce(add_uu,0);
     var b1 = u.reduce(add_uv,0);
     var c1 = 0.5*(u.reduce(add_uuu,0) + u.reduce(add_uvv,0));
     var a2 = u.reduce(add_uv,0);
     var b2 = u.reduce(add_vv,0);
     var c2 = 0.5*(u.reduce(add_vvv,0) + u.reduce(add_uuv,0));
     
     var q = a2/a1;
     var vc = (c2-q*c1)/(b2-q*b1);
     var uc = (c1-b1*vc)/a1;
     
     var r = Math.sqrt(uc*uc+vc*vc+(a1+b2)/N);
     var x = uc+xb;
     var y = vc+yb;
     
     paper.circle(x, y, r).attr({"stroke":"#f00","stroke-width":2});
     
     var e = points.reduce(function(p,c) {
       var t = r*r - (c[0]-x)*(c[0]-x) - (c[1]-y)*(c[1]-y);
       return p+t*t;
     },0);
     
     console.log("Residue = " + e);
 });
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px dotted #ccc;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
<button id="go">Compute circle</button>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: great answer! the only problem with this is that the formulas in that paper are predicated on finding the best-fit radius, but the OP says they know the radius; so the resulting circle must be best fit with _that_ radius; but that's not what the formulas in that paper give us, AFAICS.